# Undefined function 'NR' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'. MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a simple function to find the roots of a user defined equation. The function is as follows:

```
function [root] = NR(func, dfunc, x_0)

x_r = x_0;

while func(x_r) > 10^-6
    x_r = x_0 - func(x_0)/dfunc(x_0);
    x_0 = x_r;
end
root = x_r;
fprintf('The root in the given interval is %.4f\n', root)
```

I defined my function 'func' and its derivative 'dfunc' as follows

> > func=@(x) 2*x^2-3;
> >     dfunc=@(x) 4*x;

When attempting the use the function with the following input, it returns the following error messaage

> > NR(func,dfunc,-1)
> >     Undefined function 'NR' for input
> >     arguments of type 'function_handle'.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Type `which NR`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you matlab's working directory/path has the NR function

if that's not desired, you can do

```
addpath('path_where_NR_is');
```